# Ball path not following semi-circle exactly

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Bit stumped here.

First of all, here is what's going on:

[image]

As you can see, my ball is not following the curved quarter-circle path exactly, but vaguely.

Here is the code creating the quarter-circle (p.s. - my container view is 294 units tall and wide):

```
let startAngle = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2) // top of circle
let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * Double.pi * 0.25

view.layoutIfNeeded()

smallCircleView.parentVC = self
smallCircleView.layer.cornerRadius = 45/2

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: containerView.frame.self.width, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
```

And here is the code shifting the ball around:

```
func shiftSmallCircleView(newX : CGFloat){
    smallCircleViewLeadingConstraint.constant = newX
    let angle = (newX/containerView.frame.self.width)*90 + 180
    let y = containerView.frame.size.width * cos((Double.pi * 2 * angle) / 360)
    smallCircleViewBottomConstraint.constant = y + containerView.frame.origin.y
}
```

Since I'm using the cos function, should the ball's path be identical to the original quarter-circle path? How can they be similar but not identical?

Edit:
New outcome with updated code: [image]

```
let angle = (distanceDelta/containerView.frame.self.width) * -90.0
containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: angle * Double.pi/180)
```

Most recent edit:
[image]

```
let angle = (distanceDelta/pathContainerView.frame.self.width) * .pi / -180.0
containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: angle)
```

All code:

```
class SmallCircleView : UIView {

var parentVC : ViewController!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
    }
    
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        let point = touch.location(in: self.superview)=
        parentVC.shiftSmallCircleView(distanceDelta: point.x)=
    }
}

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var containerView : UIView!
@IBOutlet var pathContainerView : UIView!
@IBOutlet var smallCircleView : SmallCircleView!
@IBOutlet var smallCircleViewLeadingConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var smallCircleViewBottomConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let startAngle = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2) // top of circle
    let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * Double.pi * 0.25
    
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    smallCircleView.parentVC = self
    smallCircleView.layer.cornerRadius = 45/2
    
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: pathContainerView.frame.self.width, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    // The Bezier path that we made needs to be converted to
    // a CGPath before it can be used on a layer.
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    // apply other properties related to the path
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    // add the new layer to our custom view
    pathContainerView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    
    containerView.bringSubviewToFront(smallCircleView)
}

func shiftSmallCircleView(distanceDelta : CGFloat){
    let degrees = min(1, (distanceDelta/pathContainerView.frame.size.width)) * -90
    containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: degrees * M_PI/180)
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m on my phone right now and so I can’t provide the code but there is a much much easier way to do this. Don’t bother trying to work out what coordinates the ball needs to be at. Just place the ball into a rectangular view with the centre of this view being at the centre of your circle and the ball being on the path. (Make the container view invisible).

Now… rotate the container view.

That’s it.

Because the ball is a child of the view it will be moved as part of the rotation. And the movement will follow a circle centred around the point of rotation. Which is the centre of the container view.

## Example

I made a quick example to show what I mean. In essence... cheat. Don't actually do the hard maths to work out where the ball will be. Use methods to make it look the same in an easier way...

Here is my storyboard... [image]

And the code...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    }

    @IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let rotationAngle = sender.value * .pi / 180

        containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotationAngle))
    }
}
```

And an animation...

[image]

And if you make the container background clear...

[image]

Comment: Are you saying to rotate the view continuously AS the ball is moved?

Comment: Yeah, just apply a rotation animation to the container view. This will pivot the ball around making it follow the path that you want it to follow. Just a very basic animation that applies a rotation.

Comment: Oh I see. No, don’t move the ball like you are doing at all. Get rid of the cos and stuff. Just place the ball in a container view and rotate it. Imagine a square piece of paper with a circle in one corner. Now, when you rotate the square piece of paper the circle in the corner will follow a circular path. Thats what I’m saying to do here.

Comment: I'm not doing an animation though. The ball is being dragged in live time by the user. Will this rotation still work?

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah, should still work. If you know the amount of angle that the user has dragged then just apply that angle of rotation to the “container view”. (The piece of square paper). And it will have the same effect.

Comment: So this is the code I'm using for the transformation on the container view: let angle = (distanceDelta/containerView.frame.self.width) * -90.0
        containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: angle * Double.pi/180)

Comment: And I've added a new gif to my post showing what happens. It's close but not exact. It looks like the circle created in the transform is a bit narrower than the line I've drawn but I'm not sure how that could be because I'm using the same width in the calculation.

Comment: @AnthonyFrizalone that will depend on where the container view is and how big it is. I had to play around with mine in my example to get it just right. Try showing the container view so that you can see where it is and how it is animating. It might help you in debugging it. It looks like you're almost there though. Just need to tweak the size of the container view.

Comment: Also, I used a long thin view just to make it easier to do quickly in the example. Your view doesn't have to be that exact shape.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I've done as you've said and still not getting it correct. Now my ball is barely moving even though I have same values as you. I've played around with different denominators and it either goes nowhere or moves like crazy back and forth. I've added a new picture.

Comment: It looks like you are still moving the ball within the red view. The ball itself doesn't move at all once it's put in place inside the view. It's just the red view that moves. Don't apply any changes to where the ball is. Perhaps if you could show all the code from your view I could take a look to see what is happening.

Comment: OK - I have appended all my code. I've commented out the part that moves the ball manually and now it's just the rotation but now I'm getting basically nothing. The view to be rotated barely moves. Also, the ball is not actually inside the orange view, it's atop it. edit: I've noticed that if I lower the denominator here, the ball moves more and more until it starts to skip around. For instance if I divide by -5 instead of -180, the ball makes it about half way up the curve.

Comment: Just a note, I changed the bottom two lines to this (and it skips all over the place): let degrees = min(1, (distanceDelta/pathContainerView.frame.size.width)) * -90
        containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: degrees * M_PI/180)

Comment: I see now what's happening @Fogmeister. Because I'm rotating the view, the x value is actively changing when I move the circle and thus I'm getting sent negative x values in between the positive ones (the ones I actually want). So, because I'm not using an external slider like you, I don't think this method is going to work for me.

Comment: Ah, I fixed it! Great news - I was able to fix it by checking the touch point in the super view of the super view. So now I'm doing this: let point = touch.location(in: self.superview?.superview)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question...

I haven't double-checked your math, but this is another method of positioning your "small circle" view.

Using these two "helper" extensions:

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func pointOnCircle(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let x = center.x + radius * cos(angle)
        let y = center.y + radius * sin(angle)
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
extension CGFloat {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { self * 180 / .pi }
}
```

We can find the point on the arc for a given angle like this:

```
let arcCenter: CGPoint = .zero
let radius: CGFloat = 250
let degree: CGFloat = 45
let p = CGPoint.pointOnCircle(center: arcCenter, radius: radius, angle: degree.degreesToRadians)
```

We can then move the "ball" to that point:

```
circleView.center = p
```

To get the circle view to "roll along the inside" of the arc, we use the same center point, but decrease the radius of the arc by the radius of the circle (half the width of the view).

[image]

[image]

If you want to use that approach (rather than rotating a view with the circle in the corner), here is some example code.

Start with our extensions, an enum, and a "small circle view":

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func pointOnCircle(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let x = center.x + radius * cos(angle)
        let y = center.y + radius * sin(angle)
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
extension CGFloat {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { self * 180 / .pi }
}

enum FollowType: Int {
    case inside, center, outside
}
class SmallCircleView : UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.height / 2.0
    }
}
```

Next, a `UIView` subclass that will handle drawing the arc, adding the circle subview, **and** it will use a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` with key frames to make it interactive:

```
class FollowArcView: UIView {
    
    public var circleColor: UIColor = .red {
        didSet {
            circleView.backgroundColor = circleColor
        }
    }
    public var arcColor: UIColor = .blue { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var arcLineWidth: CGFloat = 1 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    public var arcInset: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var circleRadius: CGFloat = 25 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var followType: FollowType = .inside { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var fractionComplete: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if animator != nil {
                animator.fractionComplete = fractionComplete
            }
        }
    }
    
    private let circleView = SmallCircleView()
    private let arcLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    private var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        arcLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(arcLayer)
        
        circleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleRadius * 2.0, height: circleRadius * 2.0)
        
        circleView.backgroundColor = circleColor
        addSubview(circleView)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var curFraction: CGFloat = 0
        
        // we may be changing properties (such as arc color, inset, etc)
        //  after we've moved the circleView, so
        //  save the current .fractionComplete
        if animator != nil {
            curFraction = animator.fractionComplete
            animator.stopAnimation(true)
        }
        
        // these properties can be changed after initial view setup
        arcLayer.lineWidth = arcLineWidth
        arcLayer.strokeColor = arcColor.cgColor
        circleView.frame.size = CGSize(width: circleRadius * 2.0, height: circleRadius * 2.0)
        
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: arcInset, y: arcInset)
        let arcRadius = bounds.width - (arcInset * 2.0)
        let followRadius = followType == .inside ? arcRadius - circleRadius : followType == .center ? arcRadius : arcRadius + circleRadius
        
        let pth = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: arcRadius, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
        arcLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        
        let p = CGPoint.pointOnCircle(center: arcCenter, radius: followRadius, angle: CGFloat(90).degreesToRadians)
        circleView.center = p

        // the animator will take the current position of the circleView
        //  as Frame 0, so we need to let UIKit update the circleView's position
        //  before setting up the animator
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setupAnim()
            self.animator.fractionComplete = curFraction
        }

    }
    
    private func setupAnim() {
        
        if animator != nil {
            animator.stopAnimation(true)
        }

        // starting point
        var startDegrees: CGFloat = 90
        // ending point
        let endDegrees: CGFloat = 0
        
        // we'll be using percentages
        let numSteps: CGFloat = 100
        
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: arcInset, y: arcInset)
        let arcRadius = bounds.width - (arcInset * 2.0)
        let followRadius = followType == .inside ? arcRadius - circleRadius : followType == .center ? arcRadius : arcRadius + circleRadius

        animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, curve: .linear)
        
        animator.addAnimations {
            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, animations: {
                let stepDegrees: Double = (startDegrees - endDegrees) / Double(numSteps)
                for i in 1...Int(numSteps) {
                    // decrement degrees by step value
                    startDegrees -= stepDegrees
                    // get point on discPathRadius circle
                    let p = CGPoint.pointOnCircle(center: arcCenter, radius: followRadius, angle: startDegrees.degreesToRadians)
                    // duration is 1 divided by number of steps
                    let duration = 1.0 / Double(numSteps)
                    // start time for this frame is duration * this step
                    let startTime = duration * Double(i)
                    // add the keyframe
                    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: startTime, relativeDuration: duration) {
                        self.circleView.center = p
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        
        // start and immediately pause the animation
        animator.startAnimation()
        animator.pauseAnimation()
        
    }
    
}
```

and an example controller class:

```
class FollowArcVC: UIViewController {
    
    let followArcView = FollowArcView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let slider = UISlider()
        let typeControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Inside", "Center", "Outside"])

        [followArcView, typeControl, slider].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            followArcView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            followArcView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            followArcView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            // 1:1 ratio (square)
            followArcView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: followArcView.widthAnchor),
            
            typeControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            typeControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            typeControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            slider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            slider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
    
        typeControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        
        typeControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(typeChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        // if we want to see the view frame
        //followArcView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }

    @objc func typeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) -> Void {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            followArcView.followType = .inside
        case 1:
            followArcView.followType = .center
        case 2:
            followArcView.followType = .outside
        default:
            ()
        }
    }

    @objc func sliderChanged(_ sender: Any?) {
        guard let sldr = sender as? UISlider else { return }
        followArcView.fractionComplete = CGFloat(sldr.value)
    }

}
```

The result:

[image]

---

**Edit**

After playing around a bit, this is another way to interactively follow the path -- it uses layer path animation, and avoids the need to manually calculate keyframe positions.

Works with the same sample view controller as above - just replace the `FollowArcView` class:

```
class FollowArcView: UIView {
    
    public var circleColor: UIColor = .red {
        didSet {
            circleView.backgroundColor = circleColor
        }
    }
    public var arcColor: UIColor = .blue {
        didSet {
            arcLayer.strokeColor = arcColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    public var arcLineWidth: CGFloat = 1 {
        didSet {
            arcLayer.lineWidth = arcLineWidth
        }
    }

    public var arcInset: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var circleRadius: CGFloat = 25 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var followType: FollowType = .inside { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var fractionComplete: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            circleView.layer.timeOffset = CFTimeInterval(fractionComplete)
        }
    }
    
    private let circleView = SmallCircleView()
    private let arcLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        arcLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        arcLayer.lineWidth = arcLineWidth
        arcLayer.strokeColor = arcColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(arcLayer)
        
        circleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleRadius * 2.0, height: circleRadius * 2.0)
        
        circleView.backgroundColor = circleColor
        addSubview(circleView)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        circleView.frame.size = CGSize(width: circleRadius * 2.0, height: circleRadius * 2.0)
        
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: arcInset, y: arcInset)
        let arcRadius = bounds.width - (arcInset * 2.0)

        let pth = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: arcRadius, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
        arcLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        
        self.setupAnim()
        
    }
    
    private func setupAnim() {
        
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: arcInset, y: arcInset)
        let arcRadius = bounds.width - (arcInset * 2.0)
        let followRadius = followType == .inside ? arcRadius - circleRadius : followType == .center ? arcRadius : arcRadius + circleRadius
        
        let pth = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: followRadius, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)

        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
        
        animation.duration = 1
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
        animation.path = pth.cgPath
        
        circleView.layer.speed = 0
        circleView.layer.timeOffset = 0
        
        circleView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "PathAnim")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.circleView.layer.timeOffset = self.fractionComplete
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is excellent. I will most likely use this.