# CAKeyframeAnimation() configured for 'scrubbing', how to smooth transition to stop points?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, timing, cashapelayer, cakeyframeanimation

I'm animating an object (`CAShapeLayer`) along a bezier path by pausing the animation and setting the timeOffset manually, which moves it to fixed locations.  But the movement is jerky. I want to be able to set the next offset and have it interpolate/animate smoothly from spot to spot.  This is essentially what I'm doing. What should I do to smooth out the transitions?

```
    let bezierCurve = UIBezierPath(...)
    let shapeLayer = getShape()
    layer.speed = 0  // pause
    .
    .
    .
    let pathAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
    pathAnimation.keyPath               = "position"
    pathAnimation.path                  = bezierCurve.cgPath
    pathAnimation.calculationMode       = .paced
    pathAnimation.fillMode              = .forwards
    pathAnimation.duration              = 1
    pathAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    pathAnimation.beginTime             = CACurrentMediaTime()
    shapeLayer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: nil)
    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    .
    .
    layer.timeOffset = pathAnimation.beginTime + n  // note: periodically update n
```

Comment: Would be much easier to offer help if you provided a [mre] ... but, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610449/6257435 -- might help for your case.

Comment: @DonMag But I thought this was pretty generic, like there's some kind of approach or set of generally understood approaches to this at the guru level, like magic :-) I'm not trying to give away the farm for my widget, so I'm reluctant. Basically where I set the layer.timeOffset it simply jumps my 'shapeLayer' shape to the next position (n) along the bezierPath. I tried to animate changing n  'smoothly' by using a scheduled timer to do smaller deltas between jumps, but it seemed tacky and I couldn't get it to work. Because some of the time fields (CAMediaTime related)  kept changing.